# Input type "number" doesn't allow numbers to be entered

Tags: html, reactjs, input

I'm creating a reusable component that should be like this :

[image]

Problem: The increment/decrement buttons work fine, but when I click in the input field and type a number, nothing happens. Why?

Here is a minimal reproduced code example: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-ibj7jz?file=/src/App.js)

Here is my code:

```
const InputCounter = ({ id, label, value }: NumericInputProps) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(value ?? 0);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
      <label htmlFor={id} className="text-sm font-bold text-neutral-700">
        {label}
      </label>

      <div className="flex w-fit items-center rounded border border-solid border-neutral-300">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="h-10 w-10 rounded border -m-px mr-0 border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent focus:outline-none hover:cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => setCount(count > 0 ? count - 1 : 0)}
        >
          <IconLess width={16} height={16} />
        </button>

        <input
          id={id}
          type="number"
          value={count}
          className="h-10 w-16 rounded border-none text-center text-base font-semibold focus:outline-none"
        />

        <button
          type="button"
          className="h-10 w-10 rounded border -m-px ml-0 border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent focus:outline-none hover:cursor-pointer"
          onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}
        >
          <IconPlus width={16} height={16} />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the value in `setCount` on `onChange`, as you can see the below code, also I have update the code on [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-f8bijp?file=/src/App.js)

```
<input
  id={id}
  type="number"
  value={String(count)}
  onChange={(e) => setCount(Number(e.target.value))}
  className="h-10 w-16 rounded border-none text-center text-base font-semibold 
  focus:outline-none"
/>
```

Comment: input is of type `number`, but you are setting `value` of type `String`

Comment: That's right, if you want to remove the `string` on the value, when you replace the value from the input, there will always be a 0 with the value, so I didn't change much code, that's why I convert the value from `string`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are setting the value of `number`, but you are not hooking the change to the value of `number`, you need to consider using `onChange` on the number and try updating the value of `number`.

Updated code with few optimizations would be :

```
const InputCounter = ({ id, label, value }: NumericInputProps) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(value ?? 0);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const value = parseInt(event.target.value);
    setCount(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
  };

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    setCount((count) => Math.max(0, count - 1));
  };

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCount((count) => count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
      <label htmlFor={id} className="text-sm font-bold text-neutral-700">
        {label}
      </label>

      <div className="flex w-fit items-center rounded border border-solid border-neutral-300">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="h-10 w-10 rounded border -m-px mr-0 border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent focus:outline-none hover:cursor-pointer"
          onClick={handleDecrement}
        >
          <IconLess width={16} height={16} />
        </button>

        <input
          id={id}
          type="number"
          value={count}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          className="h-10 w-16 rounded border-none text-center text-base font-semibold focus:outline-none"
        />

        <button
          type="button"
          className="h-10 w-10 rounded border -m-px ml-0 border-solid border-neutral-300 bg-transparent focus:outline-none hover:cursor-pointer"
          onClick={handleIncrement}
        >
          <IconPlus width={16} height={16} />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```